# While google auth I am getting this error *Cross-Origin-Opener-Policy policy would block the window.closed call*

Tags: firebase, error-handling, firebase-authentication, google-oauth, mern

[image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EoZXJ.png)

I am using firebase and its google auth tool , everything works fine the user data is getting saved in the database but i get a error every time the popup window appears .
I tried many online solution but they didn't work . If somebody is familiar with this please gave me a reply ...
I am geeting the usercredential but i am not aware of this aware . What should I do now ?

Comment: Same as https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76446840/cross-origin-opener-policy-policy-would-block-the-window-closed-call-error-while